# Question regarding question about hyper planes?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am beginning to study linear algebra study and came across this exercise:

A subset of a vector subspace is called a hyperplane or more precisely a linear hyper- plane if it is a proper subspace and such that it, together with one single further vector, generates our whole vector space.

Show that: a hyperplane together with any vector not belonging to the given hyperplane generates all of our original vector space.

I'm confused as it seems the definition of a hyper plane provides the answer straight away. That is: I have a hyper plane, I have a single further vector, so I must have a generating set. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well...the definition only says that there is some vector outside the hyperplane which generates.  You are asked to prove that, in fact, you could use any vector outside the hyperplane.  I don't think it's completely obvious.

Comment: So the definition is saying 'there exists' where as I have to show that is true 'for all' vectors outside the plane. Ok, I'll have a think. Thank you

Comment: When you have an answer, post it...people will be glad to review it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things could have been worded a little differently - seems understandable for you to be missing what you're missing.

Say $V$ is the original vector space and $H$ is our hyperplane. The definition means that there *exists* a vector $x$ such that $H$ and $x$ generate $V$. The problem asks you to show that $H$ and $x$ generate $V$ for *every* $x$ (in $V$ but not in $H$).

HINT: Say $V$ is generated by $H$ and $x_0$. Say $x$ is a vector in $V$ which is not in $H$. Now *since* $H$ and $x_0$ generate $V$ it follows that $x=???$, and then the fact that $x$ is not in $H$ shows that ???

Comment: So an arbitrary vector in V can be written as a linear combination of x' and vectors in H. Follows that we can write x' as a linear combination of this arbitrary vector and vectors in H. Then we're home right? As an arbitrary vector and H generate x' so I can generate V. Is this the gist? (Sorry for late response, was eating dinner)

Comment: *sorry x' is your x_0

Comment: Sort of - you need to write it out much more carefully, explaining exactly why the things that follow follow...